# Order of hint paths in cmake find_library

Tags: cmake

I'm using `HINTS` with `find_library` and was surprised to find that the last path had priority. Is this intentional or something that can be configured.

```
set(MY_HINT_PATHS_A "/path/to/a;/path/to/b")
find_library(MY_LIBRARY_A
    NAMES MyLib
    HINTS ${MY_HINT_PATHS_A}/lib
    ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

set(MY_HINT_PATHS_B "/path/to/b;/path/to/a")
find_library(MY_LIBRARY_B
    NAMES MyLib
    HINTS ${MY_HINT_PATHS_B}/lib
    ONLY_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

message("MY_LIBRARY_A: ${MY_LIBRARY_A}")
message("MY_LIBRARY_B: ${MY_LIBRARY_B}")
```

prints

```
MY_LIBRARY_A: /path/to/b/lib/libMyLib.a
MY_LIBRARY_B: /path/to/a/lib/libMyLib.a
```

I would have expected

```
MY_LIBRARY_A: /path/to/a/lib/libMyLib.a
MY_LIBRARY_B: /path/to/b/lib/libMyLib.a
```

Comment: `${MY_HINT_PATHS_A}/lib` doesn't append `/lib` to all elements in the list, it appends `/lib` only to the **last element**: simple string concatenation. You may use `lib` with `PATH_SUFFIXEX` option to the command, but it is better to append this suffix to each path manually: `lib` suffix looks strange.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake *list* is not a *type*, but an *interpretation* of string value. So any operations on list-variables are actually operations on strings.

`${MY_HINT_PATHS_A}/lib` doesn't append /lib to all elements in the list, it appends /lib only to the last element:

```
"/path/to/b;/path/to/a/lib"
```

It is absolutely equivalent to appending `/lib` to the variable's string-value.

For get desired effect you may use `lib` with PATH_SUFFIXES option to the `find_library` command. Or directly append `/lib` suffix to every element in the list.